# How to set template in GT-521F32 fingerprint scanner?

Tags: serial-port, uart, fingerprint, biometrics

I'm working on a project using the GT-521F32 fingerprint scanner, i want to store the templates in a database in my computer rather than have them stay in the fingerprint scanner's memory. While I am able to get the templates from the fingerprint scanner and store it in my computer, I am unable to set the templates back to the fingerprint scanner. I am currently using RealTerm to send commands to the fingerprint scanner.

First, I would get the template from ID 1

```
Send command (Get template from ID 1): 
0x55 0xAA 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x70 0x00 0x71 0x01
Output: 
55 AA 01 00 00 00 00 00 30 00 30 01 (Acknowledge)
5A A5 01 00 ...(498 bytes of template data)... FD DF (Data Packet)
```

I would then delete the template in ID 1, and set the template that I got from ID 1 in ID 2

```
Send Command (Set template to ID 2):
0x55 0xAA 0x01 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x71 0x00 0x73 0x01
Output:
55 AA 01 00 00 00 00 00 30 00 30 01 (Acknowledge)
Send Command (Data packet):
0x5A 0xA5 0x01 0x00 ...(former ID 1 template data)... 0xFD 0xDF
```

Doing this doesn't result in an acknowledgement packet

Even when using the demo program provided, when I use the setTemplate option, it just results with "Communication error". How do I set templates from my computer to the fingerprint scanner's memory?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue with UART interface. Switching to the onboard USB interface (J1 pads on the bottom of the PCB) will eliminate the error message but you would need to use USB Mass Storage interface instead of UART which is not ideal.